# Output data as a Microsoft Project File

Tags: web-applications, project-management, ms-office

I'm currently developing a project management web application. One of the requirements that needs to be satisfied is exporting a project's data (Name, Activities, Deadlines and so forth) as a Microsoft Project and DotProject File, or at least as a file with a format that can easily be imported to both. Is there anyway to do this?.

If you can also post links with further information i would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are only two public sources available to my knowledge that talk about the details of the MS-Project XML file format:

- http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/ is a Java Library that is capable of reading and writing MS-Project files
- http://www.project-open.org/en/package_intranet_ganttproject is a package of the open-source ]project-open[ Project Portfolio Management (PPM) system that deals with importing and exporting MS-Project XML files.

Affiliation note: I'm a member of the ]po[ team and actually wrote the MS-Project integration package above.